# How to deploy the customistaion from one environment?ChangeSet and Salesforce IDE

Tags: apex, deployment, ide

I am new to salesforce as support developer, The vendors working on it uses ChangeSet to deploy the solution from one environment to another one. Creating changeset is ery manual and need a long time to configure the changeset package. If I ever need to recreate the changeset , it is not an easy task.

They also metioned saving the source code in source control but we can not deploy them to another sandbox environment. But from https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster , it seems we can. Can someone clairify this ? We can use eclipse to deploy salesforce customisation(apxe code , visualforce, custom object , custom field , approval workflow...) .

If we can , how we can make sure all the customisation are saved into source control?

Comment: If you are using GITHub then check out this article which shows a way to deploy directly to your Staging and Production versions of Salesforce from your repository: http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/09/24/deploy-direct-from-github-to-salesforce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in salesforce to "tear down" and rebuild. So, you essentially deploy a backup a rollback. So, having a backup in GitHub or some such form helps a bunch. This is also the reason why having a good dev-test-stage-prod cycle is good.

If you are interested in talking about tools, the company that I work for, DreamFactory Software, has a tool called SnapShot (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) that might be of interest to you. It is paid but solves a lot of issues for a lot of people. There is a free trial available for you to try it out.

Good luck!

Sridhar

Disclaimer: I work for DreamFactory, the maker of SnapShot. So, I am biased but can give you names of competing products you can test to form your own opinions.